# Adding many dropbox choosers with different extensions option does not work

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I would like to put different choosers to one page with different extensions options. So I inserted a `<div class="dropbox-chooser"></div>` to the different positions in my site. Then I wrote the following function to my head(for testing):

```
window.onload = function() {
if (document.getElementsByClassName("dropbox-chooser")) {

for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("dropbox-chooser").length; i++){
if (i === 0) {
options.extensions = ['.zip','.exe','.rar','.7zip','.php','.html','.css','.js'];['.3gp','.3gpp','.3gpp2','.avi','.mov','.mp4','.wmv','.m4v','.mpg','.mkv','.mpeg','.vob','.flv','.mts','.m2t','.ts','.dv'];
button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);alert(options.toSource());
document.getElementsByClassName("dropbox-chooser")[i].appendChild(button);
}
if (i === 2) {
options.extensions = ['.3gp','.3gpp','.3gpp2','.avi','.mov','.mp4','.wmv','.m4v','.mpg','.mkv','.mpeg','.vob','.flv','.mts','.m2t','.ts','.dv'];
button = Dropbox.createChooseButton(options);alert(options.toSource());
document.getElementsByClassName("dropbox-chooser")[i].appendChild(button);
}
}
}
}
```

and the two choosers are rendered in the right place but when I click one of the chooser buttons, the extensions option is always the last one (.3gp...) although the options.toSource() function shows the right object content for every button.

Can you please help me?
Thanks a lot!

Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Chooser doesn't look at the `options` object until the Chooser is actually opened.

You should just pass in a different object each time.

**EDIT**

Here's what I would suggest:

```
var choosers = document.getElementsByClassName('dropbox-chooser');
for (var i = 0; i < choosers.length; i++) {
    var options = {
        // ...
    };
    if (i === 0) {
        options.extensions = ['.zip', '.exe' /* ... */];
    } elif (i === 2) {
        options.extensions = ['.3gp', '.3gpp' /* ... */];
    }
    choosers[i].appendChild(Dropbox.createChooseButton(options));
}
```

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to inject the options object with a onclick method, duplication or something like that or do I really have to create all option separately my header script?

Comment: Seems like you could trivially just put that code in the loop. I'll update my answer with an example.